# Why calling the instance __proto__ returns Object{} instead of the instance it was set to?

Tags: javascript

Why callling `b.__proto__` returns `Object{}` instead of `a`?

```
var a = {
  x: 10,
  calculate: function (z) {
    return this.x + this.y + z;
  }
};

var b = {
  y: 20,
  __proto__: a
};

var c = {
  y: 30,
  __proto__: a
};
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean, I tested and `b.__proto__ === a`

Comment: @Hacketo see the attached snapshot

Comment: Are you expecting that when you type `a` in the console it returns `a`  ? `Object {x: 10}` is the value of `a`

Answer (score 0):

> Why callling b.**proto** returns Object{} instead of a?

Because the name `a` is just a name indicating how you refer to that object with x = 10 and the calculate method.

For example - if you `return` `c` from that code (as a function) the name `a` would be completely meaningless.

```
function foo(){
    var y = {x: 5};
    var z = { __proto__ : y }; // better to use Object.create
    return `;
}

// in someone else's code
var a = foo();
a.__proto__; // y wouldn't mean anything to me here, I'm not even aware of that it
a.x; // 5
```